# PHP Import to Wordpress script stuck on 504Null error

Tags: php, wordpress, import, scripting

I inherited a php script that imports .xml stories from an AWS bucket into a wordpress site.  It was running fine for awhile but now it seems that it is stuck on one record and will not skip or move forward.  I manually added the image into wordpress but it just says "image is already there, deleting".. then continues through the error loop.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
197bcf26-5b64-11eb-bcc0-00163ec2aa77.xml
Byline: Headline: 'Gone' to the top of the charts: Columbus native nominated for international folk song of the year
REP - 2021-01-28 - zone (D001)
c992fd36b34e12aef9d367c975656b43.jpg - Media does not exist in Wordpress.  Uploading it.
File is already here.  Deleting it
New media upload - Unknown status code returned: 504NULL
New media upload - Unknown status code returned: 504NULL
New media upload - Unknown status code returned: 504NULL
New media upload - Unknown status code returned: 504NULL
New media upload - Unknown status code returned: 504NULL
```

This is the section of code:

````
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Ingester');
                //var_dump($headers);
                $media_upload_output = curl_exec($ch);

                //var_dump($media_upload_output);
                //sleep(15);
                if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
                }
                $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                //var_dump($http_code);
                if ($http_code === 404) {
                    echo '404 Status code returned. Odd.  Pausing to try again: ' . PHP_EOL;
                    sleep(15);
                    goto beginmediaupload;
                } 
                elseif ($http_code === 429) {
                    echo 'Sorry.  Pausing to catch up' . PHP_EOL;
                    curl_close($ch);
                    sleep(5);
                    goto beginmediaupload;
                } 
                elseif ($http_code === 400) {
                                        echo 'Got that 400 error code' . PHP_EOL;
                    var_dump(json_decode($media_upload_output));
                                        curl_close($ch);
                                        //sleep(5);
                                        //goto beginmediaupload;
                    goto end_of_media;
                                } 
                elseif ($http_code === 503) {
                    echo 'Service unavailable.  Pausing to try again.' . PHP_EOL;
                    curl_close($ch);
                    sleep(15);
                    goto beginmediaupload;
                } 
                elseif ($http_code != 201) {
                    echo 'New media upload - Unknown status code returned: ' . $http_code;
                    var_dump(json_decode($media_upload_output));
                    sleep(15);
                    goto beginmediaupload;
                }
                curl_close($ch);
                $media_upload_output = json_decode($media_upload_output);
                //var_dump($media_upload_output);
                $sql_statement = "REPLACE INTO local_ingested_tracker (type,filename,pub,id,link) VALUES ('p','".$file_name."','".$pub_code."',".$media_upload_output->id.",'".$media_upload_output->source_url."')";
                $insert_result = $mysqli->query($sql_statement);
                $Media_Current_ID = $media_upload_output->id;
                $Media_Current_Link = $media_upload_output->source_url;
                $Media_Current_Caption = $media_upload_output->caption;
                //var_dump($media_upload_output->media_details);
                $Media_Current_Width = $media_upload_output->media_details->width;
                $Media_Current_Height = $media_upload_output->media_details->height;
                //var_dump($Media_Current_Width);
                //var_dump($Media_Current_Height);
                $Media_exists = True;
                unlink('/var/www/html/ap_feed_fetch/imgtemp/'.$file_name);
                $pheanstalk->touch($job);
                sleep(10);```

How can I add a section that will simply move on to the next record?  I'm assuming it's a bad record?  Not sure though.

Any ideas appreciated!
````

Answer (score 0):

504 is the gateway timeout - webserver did not receive a responce from PHP.
Check php.ini settings, the images might be too big and it tries to upload them, but you have limits.